# Turning on Thread Sanitizer results in signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sigabrt, thread-sanitizer

When I create a new Single View App from in Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29) and run it all is ok.

When I turn on Thread Sanitize

[image: TS option]

And try to run the very same app, I get `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

[image]

this is the backtrace

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff523d5bea libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff523d74f3 libsystem_kernel.dylib`abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 80
    frame #2: 0x00007fff523d74a3 libsystem_kernel.dylib`abort_with_reason + 19
    frame #3: 0x00007fff52469974 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_self.cold.1 + 24
    frame #4: 0x00007fff52462fe3 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_self + 34
    frame #5: 0x0000000105f2316b libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`__tsan::cur_thread() + 11
    frame #6: 0x0000000105ef8985 libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`wrap_sysctlbyname + 37
    frame #7: 0x00007fff52470331 libsystem_sim_kernel.dylib`assert_simulator_supported_host + 44
    frame #8: 0x00007fff4ff167c1 libSystem.B.dylib`libSystem_initializer + 78
    frame #9: 0x0000000105e2a3a7 dyld_sim`ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 517
    frame #10: 0x0000000105e2a7b8 dyld_sim`ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
    frame #11: 0x0000000105e259a2 dyld_sim`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 456
    frame #12: 0x0000000105e2590f dyld_sim`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 309
    frame #13: 0x0000000105e2590f dyld_sim`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 309
    frame #14: 0x0000000105e2590f dyld_sim`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 309
    frame #15: 0x0000000105e247a6 dyld_sim`ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 188
    frame #16: 0x0000000105e24846 dyld_sim`ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 82
    frame #17: 0x0000000105e19046 dyld_sim`dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 129
    frame #18: 0x0000000105e1d0fc dyld_sim`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 3831
    frame #19: 0x0000000105e181cd dyld_sim`start_sim + 122
    frame #20: 0x000000010e7f68cc dyld`dyld::useSimulatorDyld(int, macho_header const*, char const*, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*, unsigned long*) + 2308
    frame #21: 0x000000010e7f4575 dyld`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 818
    frame #22: 0x000000010e7ef227 dyld`dyldbootstrap::start(dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, int, char const**, dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, unsigned long*) + 453
    frame #23: 0x000000010e7ef025 dyld`_dyld_start + 37
(lldb)
```

I'm I missing something or using Thread Sanitizer incorrectly.

EDIT: I've opened an issue with Apple in their feedback assistant with the ID FB7513235. My open ticket in the feedback assistant indicates there are similar reported issues.

Comment: 100% reproducible from your instructions. :) I'd say report it as a bug to Apple, eh.

Comment: Thanks, will report it to apple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

issue resolved in Xcode 11.3.1

> Resolved an issue that prevented Xcode from launching processes with
>   Thread Sanitizer enabled on macOS Catalina 10.15.2. (57822138)

[see Xcode 11.3.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_3_1_release_notes)